# How can I bring back the highest value record for each item by id in my db table using Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
id      value     created_at
1       55        2018-07-16
2       25        2018-07-16
3       50        2018-07-16
1       100       2018-07-16
1       5         2018-07-16
3       11        2018-07-16
4       6         2018-07-16
```

How can I bring back each id (1, 2, 3, 4) but only the highest value record of each in an array?

1 = **100**, 2 = **25**, 3 = **50**, 4 = **6**

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX and GROUP BY

```
select id, MAX(value)  from 
your_table group by id
```